# Perspective guidelines in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, perspective

I am working on a project that will require me to build simple perspective views of real-life environments. The images need to be draw in Inkscape (I plan to extract sections layer-by-layer).

Is there any way I can set up perspective guide-lines in Inkscape to make the job easier?

At the moment, I'm thinking of roughly modelling the environments (say, a kitchen) in Sketchup to get the 3D look, saving a bitmap then using that as a guide layer in Inkspace.

BTW: I am not a graphic artist.

Comment: Perspective lines are just that...lines. Not hard to set up manually in inkscape.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but worth a revisit I think.

You can find the vanishing points in an image by extrapolating lines of perspective within it.

You can draw simple lines in Inkscape and turn them into guides by hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

This example image has two vanishing points:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the *3D boxes* tool. It allows you to create three-dimensional boxes with up to three vanishing points and keep those vanishing points consistent over many boxes. The main drawback is that you cannot convert the boxes to wireframes without converting them to paths first (as of Inkscape 0.48).

Comment: But drawing (or duplicating) a line along the relevant edge and then Object -> Objects to Guides creates really useful "infinite" guides.
Either way this is a good and fast method - the OP should accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick helping lines with the mouse by clicking in the upper ruler and pulling such horizontal lines out, or from the left ruler, pulling them to the right, or from the corners of the ruler you can pick diagonal helping lines. Modifying them to be of self defined angle isn't possible, afaik.

Maybe it is more useful to you, to draw helping lines on the base layer, and lock that layer for modification. In the end, you can make that layer invisible.

Comment: In Inkscape you can have guides at different angles, not just horizontal and vertical.

Comment: I only encountered guide lines of 0, 90 and 45/-45°, mostly by accident because they don't fit to my needs. Maybe how to changie the angle was overseen by me, maybe it changed with version 0.92. Btw.: It's a nearly 5 years old question.

Comment: I realise that, time for an update I think.

Answer (score 0):

By holding "Shift" you can modify any of those 0, 90, and 45 degree angle guide lines to an arbitrary angle. With snapping enabled, you can drag and align the guide lines to a single intersection to create a vanishing point.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but here's what I've found works pretty well.
Have a dedicated Vanishing Points layer, with semi-transparent lines. Draw a line from one vanishing point to the middle somewhere. Ctrl+D to duplicate it, and drag the end, leaving the other end at the vanishing point. While dragging, press Space to create copies wherever you want.
Repeat with the other side.